# Variadic function and variadic template overloading lookup

Tags: c++

I have a function with 2 overloaded arguments

```
template<typename... Args>
void f(Args&&...) {
    cout << "Args..." << endl;
}
 
void f(...) {
    cout << "..." << endl;
}
```

Can someone explain how does the lookup work? In my opinion, purpose of each function is the same (except first one is c++ style and second is c style). When I call function with arguments despite their types `f(5, "hello")` or `f(5, 10)` it is always variadic template (first overload), but when I call function without arguments `f()` it is always variadic function (second overload). Is there a strong rule which compiler follows to choose the right function and what is the logic behind it?

Comment: I seem to recall there's a fixed rule that keeps varargs at the bottom of the pile always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there are many rules around this in C++.

When the compiler encounters a call like `f(5, 10)`, first a list of viable candidates is synthesized, which involves instantiation of function templates (which involves [deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) of template arguments).

Then, if the list has more than one candidate, [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) is performed.

Some key overload ranking rules are:

- A better match (the one with least amount of implicit conversions) is always preferred.

  - A standard conversion is better than a user-defined conversion, which is better than the ellipsis.
- When there's no better match, the non-template version is preferred.

So in case of `f(5, 10)` we get

- `f<int,int>(int,int)` - requires 0 conversions,
- `f(...)` - requires 2 ellipsis "conversions".

The first one requires less conversions, so it wins.

In case of `f()` we get

- `f<>()` - requires 0 conversions,
- `f(...)` - requires 0 conversions.

An ambiguity, but the first one is a template, so the non-template `f(...)` is selected.